# Matching function in erlang based on string format

Tags: erlang

I have user information coming in from an outside source and I need to check if that user is active. Sometimes I have a User and a Server and other times I have User@Server. The former case is no problem, I just have:

```
active(User, Server) ->
    do whatever.
```

What I would like to do with the User@Server case is something like:

```
active([User, "@", Server]) ->
    active(User, Server).
```

Doesn't seem to work. When calling active in the erlang terminal with a@b for example, I get an error that there is no match. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A general hint: Don't keep strings around. Process them like @chops suggest as fast as possible to something else and work with that. Prefer a construction like `{User, Server}` over a string with the same content. It is more idiomatic to do so in Erlang and your pattern matching now works.

Answer (score 4):

You can tokenize the string to get the result:

```
active(UserString) ->
    [User,Server] = string:tokens(UserString,"@"),
    active(User,Server).
```

If you need something more elaborate, or with better handling of something like email addresses, it might then be time to delve into using regular expressions with the `re` module.

```
active(UserString) ->
    RegEx = "^([\\w\\.-]+)@([\\w\\.-]+)$",
    {match, [User,Server]} = re:run(UserString,RegEx,[{capture,all_but_first,list}]),
    active(User,Server).
```

**Note:** The supplied Regex is *hardly* sufficient for email address validation, it's just an example that allows all alphanumeric characters including underscores (`\\w`), dots (`\\.`), and dashes (`-`) seperated by an at symbol.  And it will fail if the match doesn't stretch the whole length of the string: (`^` to `$`).

Comment: Just a note for anyone looking for a regex for email address validation: [the HTML 5 standard has one](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address).  You'd need to add groups to it if you want to separate out username and server.

Answer (score 3):

A note on the pattern matching, for the real solution to your problem I think @chops suggestions should be used.

When matching patterns against strings I think it's useful to keep in mind that erlang strings are really lists of integers. So the string `"@"` is actually the same as `[64]` (64 being the ascii code for `@`)

This means that you match pattern `[User, "@", Server]` will match lists like: `[97,[64],98]`, but not `"a@b"` (which in list form is `[97,64,98]`).

To match the string you need to do `[User,$@,Server]`. The `$` operator gives you the ascii value of the character.

However this match pattern limits the matching string to be 1 character followed by `@` and then one more character...

It can be improved by doing `[User, $@ | Server]` which allows the server part to have arbitrary length, but the `User` variable will still only match one single character (and I don't see a way around that).